# Waterfall chart on echarts4r?

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

Hi and thanks for reading me
I'm working with a bar chart on R with the Echarts4r package, but I want to do a waterfall chart and I don't find an option to do a plot like the following on the image:
[image]

It's possible to do this chart type? The code I'm using for now is the following:

```
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  
  var = sample(LETTERS, 5),
  value = rnorm(5, mean = 200, sd = 100)
)


df |> 
  e_charts(var) |> 
  e_bar(value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether `echarts4r` offers an option out of the box but with some data wrangling you could achieve your result as a stacked bar chart like so:

Disclaimer: I borrowed the basic idea from [here](https://randyzwitch.com/ECharts.jl/waterfall).

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  var = sample(LETTERS, 5),
  value = rnorm(5, mean = 200, sd = 100)
)

df |> 
  mutate(bottom = cumsum(dplyr::lag(value, default = 0)),
         bottom = ifelse(value < 0, bottom + value, bottom),
         top = abs(value)) |>
  e_charts(var) |> 
  e_bar(bottom, stack = "var", itemStyle = list(color = "transparent", barBorderColor  = "transparent")) |>
  e_bar(top, stack = "var")
```

[image]